# Compare 2 arrays and retrieve the differences using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not a PHP expert but i'm trying Compare 2 arrays ( database relations and schema)  in PHP, I need retrieve the differences between those 2 array, I'm using this php code

```
    <?php

function maxEntities($rela, $db){
    $maxenty = array();
    $found   = false;

     foreach ($rela as $valor1) {  
      print $valor1[0] . " |  ";
    }

    print " <br \>";
     foreach ($db as $valor2) {

      print  $valor2[0] . " |  ";
    }
 $maxenty = array_diff($rela[0], $db[0]);

    print " <br \> <br \>";

    foreach ($maxenty as $valor) {

      print "  " . $valor;
    }
}
```

and this code give me this output

```
 Sale | Customer | Sale_Fee | Sale | Location | Sale | Sale | Sale_Iten | Product | Customer | Location | Sale_Iten | Sale_Fee | Region | 
Customer | Customer_Type | Fee_Type | Location | Location_Type | Period | Product | Product_Type | Region | Sale | Sale_Fee | Sale_Iten | State | 

Sale Customer_Cust_Id
```

and the output i expect is

> Period, Customer_Type, State, Location Type, Product Type and Fee Type

how i can solve my problem ?

i also tried with foreach, but give me also a wrong output

```
 foreach ($rela as $relaV) {
        foreach ($db as $dbV) {

            if ($dbV[0] == $relaV[0]) {
                $found = true;
            }
            if (!$found) {
                $found   = false;
               $maxenty[] = $dbV[0];  
            } 
        }
    }
```

in this case my output was

```
Customer
Customer_Type
Fee_Type
Location
Location_Type
Period
Product
Product_Type
Region
```

and Customer, Region, Location are in both arrays

Comment: Show us a sample of the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear, how your arrays are structured. From your code so far I guess the following structures:

```
$rela = array(array('Sale'), array('Customer'), array('Sale_Fee'), array('Sale'), array('Location'), array('Sale'), array('Sale'), array('Sale_Iten'), array('Product'), array('Customer'), array('Location'), array('Sale_Iten'), array('Sale_Fee'), array('Region'));
$db = array(array('Customer'), array('Customer_Type'), array('Fee_Type'), array('Location'), array('Location_Type'), array('Period'), array('Product'), array('Product_Type'), array('Region'), array('Sale'), array('Sale_Fee'), array('Sale_Iten'), array('State'));
```

If this is the structure of your arrays, then you can use the following code to get the difference (adopted from your foreach-approach, there may be other ways):

```
$maxenty = array();
foreach ($db as $dbValue) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($rela as $relaValue) {
        if ($relaValue[0] == $dbValue[0]) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $maxenty[] = $dbValue[0];
    }
}

print_r($maxenty);
```

This will give you the `$maxenty` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Customer_Type
    [1] => Fee_Type
    [2] => Location_Type
    [3] => Period
    [4] => Product_Type
    [5] => State
)
```